# The gradlew signingReport for the SHA-1 key is not yielding any results - VS Code

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, authentication, visual-studio-code, gradlew

I've been trying to use `./gradlew signingReport` to get the SHA-1 of my signing certificate but with no luck. I get this error:

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /home/user/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
```

I have created the project in VS Code on Ubuntu. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

Once gradlew is installed on the system. Install the debug.keystore in the system's android directory and then move to the android project in the project and run this script. It works.